# Using jQuery, how can I reference a html table cell td from a checkbox inside the cell?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table

I have an html table:

```
  <table>
         <tr>
              <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck">
              </td>
         </tr>
  </table>
```

I want to change the backcolor of the table cell when I click on the checkbox.  The table cell doesn't seem to be the parent of the checkbox.

What is the correct way to get a reference to the table cell on checkbox click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to change the backcolor of the table cell when i click on the checkbox.*

You can use currently clicked checkbox context `this` along with `.parent()` in change event to target the td element:

```
$('input[name="myCheck"]').change(function(){
  $(this).parent().css('background',this.checked?"red":"");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yf2hfdro/)**

Answer (score 1):

To get the parent table cell (e.g. the td element), you can use `.closest("td")` like this:

```
$("input").change(function() {
    var td = $(this).closest("td");
});
```

---

In this particular case, you could also just use `$(this).parent()`, but using `$(this).closest("td")` is a little more foolproof because it finds the nearest parent that is a td and would not be affected if the `input` element was put inside a div or some other HTML element for formatting reasons - so it using `.closest("td")` is less fragile and thus recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method [`.closest('td')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the closest `td` parent element.

```
$('input[name="myCheck"]').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('td');
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/odmff6ar/)

Just listen to the `change` event of the desired element and call the `.closest()` method from there.

```js
$('input[name="myCheck"]').on('change', function () {
    $(this).closest('td').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input').on('change', function () {
  if(this.checked){
     $(this).parent().css("background","blue"); 
  }
  else{
     $(this).parent().css("background","");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
         <tr>
              <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck">
              </td>
         </tr>
  </table>
```